# Internationalisation support for cordova 3.5.0

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova-3

Iam new to CORDOVA 3.5.0.I have developed an app using Cordova and i want to implement internationalisation on my app.
Kindly suggest how to do the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take a look at the i18n jquery library to implement internalization. https://github.com/jquery-i18n-properties/jquery-i18n-properties

Comment: Look at this: http://mclear.co.uk/2014/02/14/translations-language-i10n-i18n-cordova-phonegap-app/

Answer (score 0):

Some piece of code that translates:

1.Use

```
app.util.I18n.translate(menu_title)
```

2.Put on your init section

On init obtain default language from cordova:

```
navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
    function (language) {
        //alert(language.value);
        app.common.language=language.value.toLowerCase().substring(0,2);
        //alert(app.common.language);
        if(app.util.I18n.getTranslationsNames().indexOf(app.common.language) == -1){
            app.common.language = app.util.I18n.getDefaultLanguage();
        }

        inicializacionI18n();
    },
    function () {
        app.common.language = app.util.I18n.getDefaultLanguage();
        inicializacionI18n();
    }
 );
```

1. Translation function:

app.util.I18n = {
    singleton : true,

```
    config : {
        defaultLanguage : 'en',
        availableLanguages: ['en', 'es'],
        translations : {
          'en' : {
                // Menu
                'menu_title'            : 'Welcome on board {0}',
                'menu_guest'            : 'guest'
            },
          'es' : {
                // Menu
                'menu_title'            : 'Bienvenido a bordo {0}',
                'menu_guest'            : 'invitado',
            }           
        }
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        this.callParent([config]);
    },

    getDefaultLanguage: function() {
        return this.config.defaultLanguage;
    },

    getLanguage: function() {
        if(app.common.language == undefined){
            return this.config.defaultLanguage;
        }
        return app.common.language;
    },

    getTranslations: function() {
        return this.config.translations;
    },

    getTranslationsNames: function() {
        return this.config.availableLanguages;
    },

    translate: function (key) {

        // Translate
        //alert(key + "-" +app.common.language);
        if(app.common.language == undefined){
            app.common.language=this.getDefaultLanguage();
        }
        var translation = "[" + key + "]";
        if (this.getTranslations()[app.common.language][key] === undefined) {

            // Key not found in language : tries default one
            if (this.getTranslations()[this.getDefaultLanguage()][key] !== undefined) {
                translation = this.getTranslations()[this.getDefaultLanguage()][key];
            }

        } else {

            // Key found
            translation = this.getTranslations()[app.common.language][key];
        }

        // If there is more than one argument : format string
        if (arguments.length > 1) {

            var tokenCount = arguments.length - 2;
            for( var token = 0; token <= tokenCount; token++ )
            {
                translation = translation.replace( new RegExp( "\\{" + token + "\\}", "gi" ), arguments[ token + 1 ] );
            }

        }

        return translation;
    },

    format: function(text) {
        var tokenCount = arguments.length - 2;
        for( var token = 0; token <= tokenCount; token++ )
        {
            text = text.replace( new RegExp( "\\{" + token + "\\}", "gi" ), arguments[token + 1] );
        }
        return text;
    }
};
```